How to adjust the size of CircuitLab schematics?
Whenever using CircuitLab, the result is huge schematic filling the entire screen with gigantic components, example. At 2560x1440 resolution I still can't view the whole answer on screen at once. This is silly.
How do I adjust the size of the schematic so that is becomes suitable to be used on this site?
I've tried zooming in and out in CircuitLab before posting but that has no effect.

This question is similar to: Smaller CircuitLab schematics. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.   See also: CircuitLab Forum

@toolic So basically they were already aware of it in 2013 yet chose to do nothing about it...
